# Does Windows allow to rename a folder containing locked files?

Tags: windows, filesystems, lock

Being aware that the family of Windows OSes uses *mandatory file locking* while POSIX family systems use *advisory lock*, I was wondering if Windows is capable to have a directory structure renamed, while it contains one or more files that have been locked the Windows way?

Motivation: I have no access to a Windows machine, but having gone the extra mile in developing in a cross-platform way already, knowing if Windows can do that would help me out a lot. Also provided, that Window's  *mandatory file lock* mechanism is such a delight, researching the web to answer my question myself, is complicated as the web is bloated with people struggling to get rid of Windows file locks.

Comment: You can download and install Windows 10 in a virtual machine without activating it.  After a while it starts to annoy you, and then you just scratch it and do it again.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. healthy tin-foil tells me to distrust vm for sufficient isolation. distrust against Intel (M.E. + microcode), leaving little room for that otherwise valid approach.

Comment: Tip of the day:  VM's run on the same hardware as the host.  So if you don't trust the guest you don't trust the host either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot rename a folder which contains locked files.

What can happen if you attempt this in a more advanced way (like using a file manager): a new folder will be created with the target name, all files that are not locked will be moved there and the initial folder will remain as-is with the locked files.

Comment: thank you for the information. Besides some other compatibility issus that have existed "disallowed characters in file names", "file name length limitations", and "not providing a file lock for a directory", I will not be able to easily remedy this incompatibility and simply drop Win support